# Google Drive: Error in retrieving access and refresh tokens

Tags: c#, http, windows-phone-7, post, google-drive-api

I am trying to access google drive from my app for WP7. But when i try to get access token in exchange for Authorization code, I get BAD REQUEST from server.

My POST request as seen in Fidler:

```
POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Referer: file:///Applications/Install/7128457C-3AF4-41C4-A606-742068B1463F/Install/
Content-Length: 240
Accept-Encoding: identity
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: NativeHost
Host: accounts.google.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache

code=<*Authorization_Code*>&
client_id=<*My_Client_Id*>&
client_secret=<*My_Client_Secret*>&
redirect_uri=urn%3aietf%3awg%3aoauth%3a2.0%3aoob&
grant_type=authorization_code
```

Response from server:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Date: Sat, 07 Sep 2013 14:05:35 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN 
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Server: GSE
Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

21
{
   "error" : "invalid_request"
}
0
```

My Code:

```
StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
postData.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", "code",        HttpUtility.UrlEncode(AuthorizationCode));
postData.AppendFormat("&\n{0}={1}", "client_id", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ClientId));
postData.AppendFormat("&\n{0}={1}", "client_secret", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ClientSecret));
postData.AppendFormat("&\n{0}={1}", "redirect_uri", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"));
postData.AppendFormat("&\n{0}={1}", "grant_type", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("authorization_code"));

WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.UploadStringCompleted += TokenResponse;
client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

client.UploadStringAsync(new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",UriKind.Absolute), "POST", postData.ToString());
```

I get this result both on emulator as well as Lumia 820. I also tried without using HttpUtility in POST request but didn't work. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its likely due to the fact that you are adding a new line via `\n` between all the param/value pairs.

I do it without that without it and it works - https://github.com/entaq/GoogleAppsScript/blob/master/IO2013/YouTubeAnalytics/oauth2.gs#L25